# Can hololens do object detection? Or how to use YOLO/tensorflow/tesseract in Hololens

Tags: tesseract, object-detection, hololens, yolo, text-recognition

I'm testing some function in Hololens. Want to know whether it is possible to use any of object detection/text recognition in Hololens?

Comment: I searched it in Google and found some sources. Did you try?

Comment: I did but none of them built successfully. Or am i missing something...?

Comment: But if u mean Vuforia. I tried too but's not what I am looking for, i testing more of like open source

Answer (score 2):

Hololens 1 doesn't natively support object detection, you'll need to use third-party code.

OpenCV is a good starting point, as it is open source and well known/regarded.  There are [various](https://github.com/EnoxSoftware/HoloLensWithOpenCVForUnityExample) guides on installing/using it, and also a good ready-build [Unity asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088) which would could consider.

Hololens V2 is looking like it will integrate well with the azure cloud, and will likely support remote object detection/recognition.  But for now I would recommend OpenCV.